# How to print out object properties within for-in loop?

Tags: javascript, logging, for-loop

I'm getting a list of objects from an API which looks like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "date": "2014-09-25 19:00:00", 
      "title": "Hitjeskanon"
    }, 
    {
      "date": "2014-09-25 21:00:00", 
      "title": "Black & White ESN House & Techno"
    }, 
    {
      "date": "2014-09-25 21:00:00", 
      "title": "Hit It!"
    }
  ]
}
```

I now get these results from the API, and want to log them, which I try as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/eventSearch/" + q,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result['results']);
        for (event in result['results']) {
            console.log(event['title']);
        }
    }
});
```

In the console, I correctly see the objects with the first two logs, but the `console.log(event['title'])` only prints out `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Try using something else instead of the variable `event`.

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` for iterating through arrays in JavaScript. Use a numeric index, or use the `.forEach()` function.

Comment: results is an array, you need a simple for loop. also prefix event with var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result['results']` is actually an Array. So, you should iterate it with normal for loop like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < result['results'].length; i += 1) {
    console.log(result['results'][i]['title']);
}
```

Or you can use `Array.prototype.forEach` like this

```
result['results'].forEach(function(currentObject) {
    console.log(currentObject['title']);
});
```

Also, you can access the attributes with the dot operator, like this

```
    console.log(result.results[i].title);
```

or

```
    console.log(currentObject.title);
```

Comment: ... and of course `result.results[i].title` would work too :)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea for more discussion on this `for-in` with JavaScript arrays problem.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a traditional `for` loop, but if you don't need random access (e.g., `results[2]`) you can use a `for...of` statement (introduced in ECMAScript6). In your code, just change `for...in` to `for...of`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/eventSearch/" + q,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result['results']);
        for (event of result['results']) {
            console.log(event['title']);
        }
    }
});
```

And like @thefourtheye mentioned, you can access the `results` array and the event's `title` property with the dot operator:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/eventSearch/" + q,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.results);
        for (event of result.results) {
            console.log(event.title);
        }
    }
});
```

This page is a great reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of